# Weird Browser Pictures on Mac Mavericks

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, firefox, web-browser

Can someone please tell me what's happening here : http://awesomescreenshot.com/02c2otqbf9 This can be fixed by clearing my cache. Pictures are broken.

My OS is MAC Mavericks, happens on all browsers including Windows browser ( Virtual Box )

But this happens a alot on all the websites I'm doing it's frustrating.

Update:

Also happens on desktop pictures : [image]

Thanks!

Comment: When I open the links they look normal. So can you publish a screen shot (link) of what you are seen!

Comment: I Think is a good sample, here's an image url http://mountainviewweightloss.com/images/default/bg-grunge.png . But this is what I see http://awesomescreenshot.com/0982oumgb5

Comment: Both of your examples show that the awesome screen shot capture does not work. So disable that plug in, or see them for fixing the problem.

Comment: Hi @Buscar웃 . Sorry I can't seem to understand how Awesome screenshot is the root of all of this since it also affects my Desktop pictures as seen here http://i.stack.imgur.com/vhZ3g.jpg ( the thumbnail is damaged and has a Red color on the image )

Comment: Hi @Buscar웃 , I've removed my add ons on chrome. But the problem still persist. https://www.evernote.com/shard/s350/sh/26fa7843-f141-4e00-b719-3b246cbbecc7/e3eb2a091a1deb56858e0d24848005fe/deep/0/Northern-Westchester-Hospital.png

Comment: All I can see is you are showing a Web screenshots folder as desktop pictures.

Comment: 2nd screenshot : This time the pic is more damaged than the other one. https://www.evernote.com/shard/s350/sh/d66f7758-56b5-4379-8e0f-fbad0e9d8f8e/f5b14d702df50f5e3bd3c5a17e5eb375/deep/0/Northern-Westchester-Hospital.png

Comment: Please use the cmd-shift-4 and select a screen portion in a browser the look at that screen shot.

Comment: this is a known issue with Mavericks, which has many bugs to learn more, google: Mavericks display artifacts

Answer (score 1):

I can not help you further then explained in my answer below.

You have installed a add-on with some "other" software from a 3d party.

That one is causing all your problems.

You can try to talk to the [developer](http://www.diigo.com/), or do a clean uninstall of the application and all its by products on your computer.

---

Well, it is a bit a spam if you want to call it that way.

When you open that web site and click on it, you will get a browser add on.

[image: browser add on]

When you hover over the "Firefox version" (in my case), you will see following in the bottom left corner:

[image: add on]

To get rid of it, open your browsers preferences and remove that add on.

PS:

in my case it shows the Firefox version (add on), since i used it to get the page.

I used the standard os x screen capture for the images in here.

EDIT:

I recommend you get rid off that add-on asap since it installs stuff you do not want!

Also remove all web screen shots taken by that POS! including in your desk top collection.

[image: spam]